# Issue in deploying a Java web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, webserver

Im not sure how to put up this question.

Im writing a webapplication and using a 3rd party jar to get an XML data from it.
The jar requires few property files to be placed along with it in the application for it to work.
When using the jar in an independent java application, it seems to work fine.
When using that java code in the web application, jar in unable to access the property file.

My best guess is that while deploying the weapp, the web server is not able to access the property files.
Im not sure where to place those files, for my application to work.

Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

/WEB-INF/classes is the normal place to put property files but that assumes that the JAR is using the class loader to find them. If it is using the current working directory that is going to be a lot messier. The working directory for Tomcat is usually $CATALINA_HOME/bin so you don't really want to be putting application specific files in there.